# Protecting Directories in a chroot'ed root fs

Tags: permissions, filesystems, access-control-list, chroot

So we're trying to retrofit an older ftp drop off server that also doubles as a rsync endpoint. In each user 
chroot there's a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/.
├─── usr/
├─── lib/
└─── ...(customer data)
```

Ideally we'd add a `/data` directory in the chroot and have told customers years ago to send their data there. However we did not do so in the past and cannot change the structure in the near future.

I was wondering if there's a combination of permissions that would allow my user to still create new files in the / directory but not move or rename the two directories that currently exist. I assume this can be done with ACLs but I don't know how. So as a Test

1. `echo cust_data > customer_file` : Should be allowed
2. `mv customer_file customer_file2` : Should be allowed
3. `mkdir customer_dir` : Should be allowed
4. `rm usr` : Should be disallowed
5. `mv usr usr_something` : Should be disallowed

Is there an ACL policy I can set to make this so?

Comment: Hmm. I suggest that you forcibly convert anyone to the new structure who breaks their chroot by doing one of these things.

Comment: I am not sure this is realistic with ACLs alone. It might be something you could use seLinux to do. It sounds a lot easier to chmod 500 the chroot, and start enforcing the use of /data

Answer (score 0):

Set the ownership of the chroot `/` directory to `root:root`:

```
chown root:root /path/to/chroot/rootdir
```

then set the *sticky bit*:

```
chmod 1777 /path/to/chroot/rootdir
```

Leave `/usr` and `/lib` as-is, presumably something like `root`-owned and `root`-only writable.  That will leave users able to manipulate files as they want to, but unable to modify `/usr` and `/lib` in any way.

Per [the Linux `chmod.1` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html):

> The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose
>          interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it
>          prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the
>          directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called
>          the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly found
>          on world-writable directories like `/tmp`.  For regular files on some
>          older systems, the bit saves the program's text image on the swap
>          device so it will load more quickly when run; this is called the
>          *sticky bit*.